# Write a function that integrates another function in R

Tags: r, function

I wrote this function which works.
for another function, I need to integrate this one.

```
    Shatc<-function(t){
  for (i in 1:n) {
  if(censoring$ctime[i]<t){
    d[i]<-sum(censoring$cens[1:i])
    num[i]<-n-(d[i]-1)
    sc[i]<-1-(d[i]/num[i])
  }
    else{
      break
    }
  }
  prod(sc)
}
> Shatc(0.2)
[1] 0.583874
> Shatc(0.4)
[1] 0.01419291
```

here is the second function

```
whatC<-function(t){
  integrate(Shatc,lower=0,upper=t)$value    
}
```

but when I run whatC, this error shows

```
Error in integrate(Shatc, lower = 0, upper = t) : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (censoring$ctime[i] < t) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (censoring$ctime[i] < t) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (censoring$ctime[i] < t) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (censoring$ctime[i] < t) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5: In if (censoring$ctime[i] < t) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Hi, please share a reproducible sample of your data with `dput(head(data))` so that we could use it and you will have a better chance of getting a good relevant response.

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate without `censoring`, `d`, `num`, and `sc`, but it looks like you need to vectorize `Shatc`.

`integrate` will send an array to the function it is integrating, and it expects an array output. The `Vectorize` function should work:

```
whatC<-function(t){
  integrate(Vectorize(Shatc),lower=0,upper=t)$value    
}
```